# Symfony, redirecting depending on a variable

Tags: symfony

I'm building a shop system at the moment. Using Symfony+CommerceTools as backend and Twig as frontend.

What I want to achive:
In store A, called with a.store.com, you should be always redirected to /login page if you arent logged in yet. This store can only be used when logged in.
In store B, called with store.com, you can access anything without being logged in.

Right now, anyone can access everything. Thats right for store B.
I could add a rule to the security.yaml, that redirects to /login if not logged in, that would work for store A.

But I need a solution, that have both. Depending on a variable in commerceTools.

Comment: Use [firewalls](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What keeps you from writing code that handles this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have logins set up this is quite straight forward using roles in Symfony. If you don't have a login form set up yet check out this [Symfony login guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).

To use roles you will have to ensure you have your security system set up which is in this [Symfony Security guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) - Note this will need to be set up first if you intend to use the Symfony login forms I linked to first.

- The bit you need in particular to restrict access to certain sections of your site is **Section 4) Denying Access, Roles and other Authorization** in the above guide.
- Essentially in your User entity class you have **roles** set to your users. Then, my preferred way of securing certain parts of your site would be by adding role requirements into the controllers for the views you want to secure, for example:

```
// src/Controller/ShopAController.php
// ...

public function shopA(): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');
}
```

- You will notice when setting up the security system, that there are settings to give any *registered* users the role of ROLE_USER, so you can use this to secure parts of your site to only registered users, or you could create a new role such as ROLE_CUSTOMER or something.
- If a none logged in user tries accessing this secured view, they will be redirected to the login page.
- Then for the views of your site you want anyone to be able to access you simply don't set any role access rules in those controllers.
- This avoids needing to add URL paths to your security.yaml as you wanted as well.

I hope this was helpful! Give it a try and follow the Symfony tutorials I linked, they're very easy to follow :)